# MySQL to GeoMesa through .csv

Tags: mysql, csv, geomesa

I have a MySQL table whose data I have to export to .csv and then ingest this .csv to GeoMesa.

**My Mysql table structure is like below:**

> [[image: MySQL table description[1]]

Now, as you can see the **the_geom** attribute of table has data type point and in database it is stored as blob like shown below:

> [image: MySQL sample data]

**Now I have two problems :**

1. When I export the MySQL data into a (.csv) file my csv file shows (...) for the_geom attribute as shown below instead of any binary representation or anything which will allow it to be ingested in GeoMesa. So, how to overcome this?

> [image: the_geom attribute of MySQL table]

2. Csv file also shows # for any attribute with datetime datatype but if you expand the column the date time can be seen as sown in below picture (however my question is does it will cause problem in geomesa?).

> [image: Attribute with datetime datatype shown as # because of column width]

Answer (score 0):

For #1, MySQL's export is not automatically converting the Point datatype into text for you.  You might need to call a [conversion function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-format-conversion-functions.html) such as AsWKT to output the geometry as [Well Known Text](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text).  The WKT format can be used by GeoMesa to read in the Point data.

For #2, I think you'll need to do the same for the date field.  Check out the date and time [functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html).